# Add value repeatedly in Python

Tags: python

This might be very simple, but I'm having trouble finding the answer (possibly because it is difficult to figure out how to format the question).

I would like to do in Python what I can do in Excel, wherein there is a set value (set with the `$`) that can be repeatedly added to the previous value in order to generate a list.

For example:

```
1 + 4 = 5,
5 + 4 = 9,
9 + 4 = 13, et cetera.
```

I feel like the answer is obvious, but I am struggling to figure out what it is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the answer is indeed obvious, so before giving you the solution I want you to look into `while` loops and `list` objects (how to create and append to them). Then explain where you are stuck trying to use these  principles.

Comment: frame your question properly...
what are the inputs and outputs

Comment: @timgeb it's not clear if `list`s even come into this so asking for clarification is more prudent than strongly suggesting they go read the manual for something that isn't relevant...

Comment: @JonClements OP says he wants to generate a list.

Comment: @timgeb ahh... my bad - tired eyes must have glossed over that bit. Anyway - looks a bit more like `range` may be a good choice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use a [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) with a specific step:

```
>>> range(1, 100, 4)
[1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 33, 37, 41, 45, 49, 53, 57, 61, 65, 69, 73, 77, 81, 85, 89, 93, 97]
```

and in Python3:

```
>>> list(range(1, 100, 4))
[1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 33, 37, 41, 45, 49, 53, 57, 61, 65, 69, 73, 77, 81, 85, 89, 93, 97]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop and your set value in a variable. Not exactly sure what you meant by generating a list. Consider the following:

```
def addManyTimes(self, howManyTimes, initialValue, constantValue):
    your_list = []
    for x in range(howManyTimes):
        initialValue += constantValue
        your_list.append(initialValue)
    return your_list
```

Answer (score 0):

The above works really well, but if you want to display the calculation in your list, as you state above, then try this.

```
num = input("Number here:")
num_list = []
while True:
    addNum = input("Add number :")
    try:
        sumNum = int(num)+int(addNum)
        num_list.append(num+" + "+addNum+" = "+str(sumNum))
        print(num_list)
        num = str(sumNum)
    except TypeError:
        print("Pease insert a valid whole number")
```

Your list will look like this:
[1+2=3,3+4=5,5+9=14]....

Correct me if I misunderstood the question.